# Custom position/parent for a MatBottomSheet

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I would like to position a MatBottomSheet as a child to a parent element.  For example I have a Nav element on the left side of my page and I would like the bottom sheet to be contained within that nav element rather than the entire page.

The viewContainerRef seemed like a good place to start;
https://material.angular.io/components/bottom-sheet/api

However according to this ticket that does not change where the sheet is placed within the overlay container.  https://github.com/angular/components/issues?q=matbottomsheet+

Is it possible in angular material to constrain the bottom sheet to a specific element rather then the entire page?